# Unable to do loop over objects

Tags: java

I am trying to create a visual grid of this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-coordconvert/ -Military Grid Reference System.  I have the latitude/longitude to UTM and also to MGRS...which ar

17 T 330649 4689666

17TLG3064989666

But when going from MGRS to latitude I get the following:
`[D@18e3f02a`

```
public class CoordinateConversion {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        CoordinateConversion test = new CoordinateConversion();
        CoordinateConversion test2 = new CoordinateConversion();
        test.latLon2UTM(35.58, 82.56);
        System.out.println(test.latLon2UTM(42.340837, -83.055821));
        System.out.println();
        test2.latLon2UTM(35.58, 82.56);
        System.out.println(test2.latLon2MGRUTM(42.340837, -83.055821));

        CoordinateConversion test3 = new CoordinateConversion();
        test3.latLon2UTM(35.58, 82.56);
        //System.out.print(test3.mgrutm2LatLong(42.340837, -83.055821));
        //System.out.println(test3.mgrutm2LatLong("02CNR0634657742"));


        MGRUTM2LatLon mg = new MGRUTM2LatLon();
        //mg.convertMGRUTMToLatLong("02CNR0634657742");
        String MGRUTM = "17TLG3064989666";
        System.out.println(mg.convertMGRUTMToLatLong(MGRUTM));
        //for loop to be developed

    }

    public double[] utm2LatLon(String UTM) {
        UTM2LatLon c = new UTM2LatLon();
        return c.convertUTMToLatLong(UTM);
    }

    public double[] mgrutm2LatLon(String MGRUTM) {
        MGRUTM2LatLon c = new MGRUTM2LatLon();
        return c.convertMGRUTMToLatLong(MGRUTM);
    }
}
```

and from this class:

```
public double[] convertMGRUTMToLatLong(String mgrutm) {
    double[] latlon = {0.0, 0.0};
    // 02CNR0634657742
    int zone = Integer.parseInt(mgrutm.substring(0, 2));
    String latZone = mgrutm.substring(2, 3);

    String digraph1 = mgrutm.substring(3, 4);
    String digraph2 = mgrutm.substring(4, 5);
    easting = Double.parseDouble(mgrutm.substring(5, 10));
    northing = Double.parseDouble(mgrutm.substring(10, 15));

    LatZones lz = new LatZones();
    double latZoneDegree = lz.getLatZoneDegree(latZone);

    double a1 = latZoneDegree * 40000000 / 360.0;
    double a2 = 2000000 * Math.floor(a1 / 2000000.0);

    Digraphs digraphs = new Digraphs();

    double digraph2Index = digraphs.getDigraph2Index(digraph2);

    double startindexEquator = 1;
    if ((1 + zone % 2) == 1) {
        startindexEquator = 6;
    }

    double a3 = a2 + (digraph2Index - startindexEquator) * 100000;
    if (a3 <= 0) {
        a3 = 10000000 + a3;
    }
    northing = a3 + northing;

    zoneCM = -183 + 6 * zone;
    double digraph1Index = digraphs.getDigraph1Index(digraph1);
    int a5 = 1 + zone % 3;
    double[] a6 = {16, 0, 8};
    double a7 = 100000 * (digraph1Index - a6[a5 - 1]);
    easting = easting + a7;

    setVariables();

    double latitude = 0;
    latitude = 180 * (phi1 - fact1 * (fact2 + fact3 + fact4)) / Math.PI;

    if (latZoneDegree < 0) {
        latitude = 90 - latitude;
    }

    double d = _a2 * 180 / Math.PI;
    double longitude = zoneCM - d;

    if (getHemisphere(latZone).equals("S")) {
        latitude = -latitude;
    }

    latlon[0] = latitude;
    latlon[1] = longitude;
    return latlon;
}
```

I am trying not to get into a large library where I will have to learn things that may be time consuming.

So I am trying to loop so I go east (easting) and north (northing) and cannot get past the point where I have one point - latitude/longitude.

Hope I have asked my question clearly without stating too much.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Terry

Comment: Override `toString()` in the class you are trying to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method convertMGRUTMToLatLong(String s) you are returning an array **latlon** (i.e an object).
It returns its hashcode which is probably u dont want.
You want to print the array values. So in your main method you replace below line;

```
System.out.println(mg.convertMGRUTMToLatLong(MGRUTM));
```

with

```
    double[] a = mg.convertMGRUTMToLatLong(MGRUTM) ;
System.out.println(a[0]+" " + a[1] );
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That did it nanosoft...thanks. This link http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up says I should be able to vote is up. I do not see an arrow. Me reputation is at 15. Would like to do that but not not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Your result from `convertMGRUTMToLatLong()` is an array of `double`s, and by default, arrays are converted to String in a rather unreadable format in Java. That's where the `[D@18e3f02a` comes from. Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mg.convertMGRUTMToLatLong(MGRUTM)));` and you'll get a more readable output.

Comment: Michael, the answer above from nanosoft worked but for future reference as far as your response, am I reading "Arrays" to literally. Because I get the "Arrays cannot be resolved". Probably will figure it out but not yet.

Comment: Like most other classes, you need to import `Arrays` class before using it - add `import java.util.Arrays;` at the top of your program.